# How to get exact difference between two dates along with time in Java?

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have two date objects.When i use the `after` method on date object.It's not giving the correct reulst.Here my code is

```
DateandTime1=Thu Dec 26 08:05:42 IST 2013     
DateandTime2=Thu Dec 26 07:15:40 IST 2013
```

`DateandTime1` and `DateandTime2` are two `Date` objects.If I write code like `boolean result=DateandTime1.after(DateandTime2)`, then `result` value should be 'false'. But it's giving me 'true'. May I know what is the reason and please let me know if there is any way to get exact difference.

Comment: Well, the first `Date` is later than the second `Date`.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments said your first `Date` is after your second `Date`, which is why the call `DateandTime1.after(DateandTime2)` returns `true`.

As for your second question, you can get the exact difference between two dates by doing

```
long difference = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
```

this will return the difference in milliseconds. If you want to convert that to another time measurement you can use the `TimeUnit` enum. E.g.:

```
long differenceInHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(difference);
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Class : java.​util.​Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29)**

```
public boolean after(Date when)
```

Tests if this date is after the specified date.

**Returns:**
`true` if and only if the instant represented by this Date object is strictly later than the instant represented by when; `false` otherwise.

So 8 after 7 is Yes.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, I tried this in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3. Sure enough, 8 comes after 7.

As for "exact difference", in what form do you want it? Seconds? Milliseconds? Hours, minutes, and seconds? In my code example below I use the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) class in Joda-Time to render the standard [ISO 8601 "duration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) in the format of "PnYnMnDTnHnMnS".

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

//        DateandTime1=Thu Dec 26 08:05:42 IST 2013
//        DateandTime2=Thu Dec 26 07:15:40 IST 2013

// Specify a time zone rather than depend on default.
// By "IST" did you mean India Standard Time or Irish Standard Time?
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Asia/Kolkata" );

DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime( 2013, 12, 26, 8, 5, 42, timeZone );
DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime( 2013, 12, 26, 7, 15, 40, timeZone );

Period period = new Period( dateTime2, dateTime1 );

Boolean is8After7 = ( dateTime1.isAfter( dateTime2 ) );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTime1: " + dateTime1 );
System.out.println( "dateTime2: " + dateTime2 );
System.out.println( "is8After7: " + is8After7 );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

When run…

```
dateTime1: 2013-12-26T08:05:42.000+05:30
dateTime2: 2013-12-26T07:15:40.000+05:30
is8After7: true
period: PT50M2S
```